# PHP Can't Get Just One Value

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="function.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="data" value="data" hidden="">
      <input type="file" name="url">
      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" class="rounded-0 btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

function.php

```
if ($_POST['upload']) {
    
    echo $_POST['data'];
    echo $_POST['url'];
}
```

output; data

I'm getting data value but url not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

İnstead of $_POST['url'] use $_FILES["url"]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for file upload.

```
<?php
       if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($_FILES);
          exit;
       }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if(isset($_POST['upload'])))